# Redshift - extracting constraints

Tags: amazon-redshift

How to get exported keys (database metadata).Even though redshift does not support foreign keys and primary keys I am able to see them in system tables.
The problem here is in the system table the multiple columns of a foreign key exist as an array in one column(though redshift doesn't support arrays). Is it possible to extract them in one query.

Comment: Redshift does support foreign keys and primary keys: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-defining-constraints.html Can you post the query you used to look at the system table ? and the result?

Answer (score 5):

Use table_constraints table:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_constraints;
```

Comment: bonus round: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_constraints where table_name = <tablename>`